# Discrete sets in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $D$ be a discrete set in the norm topology of a normed space $X$. Does $D$ remain discrete in the weak topology of $X$? What if $D$ is moreover closed?

Comment: What is a "norm discrete set"? Google search turns up your post and nothing else.

Comment: @MattN.: Discrete in the norm topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. That of course makes sense. Perhaps one could call it *obvious*, even.

Answer (score 4):

No. For an example, consider $X=\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ and $D=\lbrace 0, e_1,e_2,\ldots \rbrace$ with the usual unit vectors. Then $D$ is norm-discrete
as the distance between two points in $D$ is at least $1$ but $D$ is not
weakly dicrete because $e_n \to 0$ weakly.